# Does this leak memory?

Tags: c++, memory

The addStudent function and mainMenu function are the two that are important.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Student
{
   string name;
   string major;
   Student *p_next;
};

Student *addStudent(Student *p_students)
{
   Student *p_new_student = new Student;
   cout << "Student name: \n";
   cin >> p_new_student->name;
   cout << p_new_student->name << "'s major: \n";
   cin >> p_new_student->major;

   Student *p_place_holder = new Student;
   Student *p_all_students = new Student;
   p_all_students = p_students;
   p_place_holder = NULL;

   if (p_students == NULL) // Adds the first element to the linked list which was initialized to NULL
   {
      p_new_student->p_next = p_students;
      delete p_place_holder;
      delete p_all_students;
      return p_new_student;
   }

   else // Adds elements beyond the first element to the linked list
   {
      while (p_all_students != NULL)
      {
         if (p_new_student->name.compare(p_all_students->name) <= 0)
         {
            if (p_place_holder == NULL) /* if p_new_student->name is before
            p_all_students->name and p_all_students is still the first element in the list*/
            {
               p_new_student->p_next = p_all_students;
               p_all_students = p_new_student;
               delete p_place_holder;
               return p_all_students;
            }

            else
            {
               p_new_student->p_next = p_all_students;
               p_place_holder->p_next = p_new_student;
               return p_students;
            }

         }

         else if (p_new_student->name.compare(p_all_students->name) > 0)
         {
            p_place_holder = p_all_students;
            p_all_students = p_all_students->p_next;
         }
      }
   }
}

void mainMenu(Student *p_students)
{
   int response = 0;
   cout << "1. Add Student\n";
   cout << "2. View Students\n";
   cin >> response;

   if (response == 1) // calls addStudent 4 times and then mainMenu
   {
      p_students = addStudent(p_students);
      p_students = addStudent(p_students);
      p_students = addStudent(p_students);
      p_students = addStudent(p_students);
      mainMenu(p_students);
   }

   else if (response == 2) // lists the students and their majors and then exits
   {
      while (p_students != NULL)
      {
         cout << p_students->name << '\n';
         cout << p_students->major << "\n\n";
         p_students = p_students->p_next;
      }
   }

   delete p_students; // hopefully deletes all allocated memory
}

int main()
{
   Student *p_students = new Student;
   p_students = NULL;

   mainMenu(p_students);
}
```

Basically wondering if "delete p_students;" in the mainMenu function will properly delete all allocated memory so that the program doesn't leak memory. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a lot of code, you should try to reduce it to minimal compileable code that will still describe the problem.

Comment: Also, if you run your program through a utility like _valgrind_, you'll see if it leaks memory without having to ask here!

Comment: @MrLister: It's much better to be able to read and reason about code to prevent leaks.

Comment: Sorry for the long code segment, I'm new here so I appreciate the pointer (pun intended) on proper etiquette. I will also look into the program you mentioned and try to use that in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These lines will leak an instance of Student:

```
Student *p_place_holder = new Student;
Student *p_all_students = new Student;
p_all_students = p_students;
p_place_holder = NULL;
```

You allocate a Student, assign it to `p_place_holder`, then later overwrite the pointer with NULL without deleting the instance.

You also have:

```
p_students = addStudent(p_students);
p_students = addStudent(p_students);
p_students = addStudent(p_students);
p_students = addStudent(p_students);
```

which will overwrite `p_students` three times without trying to free the memory in the old value.

The larger problem is you end with `delete p_students`, but that won't examine the `Student` structure to find the pointer within it, delete it, etc, recursively, as you are hoping.  You are leaking almost all of the memory you've allocated.

I think you are misunderstanding how new and delete pair together.

Comment: I am, this is my first program using the two. If I use delete in the addStudent function, it would delete the p_students student which I'm using to point to the first item in the list correct? Should I assign p_students to a new Student and then delete the old one each time the function is called?

Comment: Oh also, would a while loop work at the end of mainMenu to delete all of the instances of Student within the linked list? Such as while(p_students != NULL) { //code }?

Comment: @BlakeMadden: every time you abandon a pointed-to value, you need to delete it.  That could be when you overwrite a pointer, or when you delete a struct that itself has a pointer in it.

Comment: so inside the addStudent function when I delete p_place_holder and p_new_student before I return p_students, when I go to list the students it won't list them presumably because I just deleted them

Comment: I was using those two pointers as place holders so that I did not inadvertently change what p_students points to since that is the head of the list.

Comment: Alright well thank you for your help, I'll try and figure out where I can and can't use delete to free up memory.

Answer (score 0):

You must use enforced-ownership pointers to avoid memory leaks- for example, `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. You can never effectively prevent leaks with `delete`.

Comment: "never"? Amazing any software got written at all before these classes were available... :)

Comment: I use `new` / `delete` exclusively and never have any issues. I guess it's handy to have some experience. And for the cases where problems pop up, Valgrind is a very effective help.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: People just lived with the bugs. Also, software was much, much smaller and much less complex then.

Comment: @Ned: Or, maybe, they just wrote smart pointers themselves, because they noticed how ridiculous manual memory management is.

Comment: @DeadMG: you're joking, right?  It is much easier to write correct software with helpers like you mention, or even better, with languages that abstract this kind of stuff for you.  But "never" and "they lived with the bugs" and "smaller and less complex" make you look like you have no sense of the work people did before you arrived on the scene.  Also, however small software was 20 or 50 years ago, it was longer than the OP's code, so surely we can help him understand how to apply some discipline to prevent leaks.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: It's true that the OP's program is still well within the complexity you can cope with. But why would you? You're just going to have to learn to `unique_ptr` anyway. What I said is still true for the general case, today.

Comment: The extent of my experience with C++ is 150 pages of a book that I'm learning from, so I'm trying to take it one step at a time and learn everything I can about the fundamentals of the language so that I fully understand exactly what I'm doing when implementing things like you are talking about.